# HTML/PHP Survery not passing ID from table correctly

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

I'll try to keep it simple... this is the code I am using to populate a dropdown menu from a database. This populates the dropdown menu correctly.

```
<form action="formsubmit.php?team_id=6" method="post">
    <label> <br />What did they say?: <br />
        <textarea name="quotetext" rows="10" cols="26"></textarea></label>
    <select name='name'>
        <?php
            while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                echo "<option value=" . $temp['id'] . ">".htmlspecialchars($temp['lastname']) . ", " . htmlspecialchars($temp['firstname']) . "</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

What I'm attempting to do is pass the person's ID into along to the file formsubmit.php which is called on the submission of the form. When I use $die($sql) on my database query in formsubmit.php, the ID of the person is blank.... everything else gets passed through just fine. Here is the relevant code in formsubmit.php:

```
$quotetext = $_POST['quotetext'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $team_id = $_GET['team_id'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO quotes SET 
            speaker_id='$id',
            quotetext='$quotetext',
            game_id=2";
    die($sql);
```

EDIT: Fixed, credit to Michael.

```
<select name='name'>
```

Should be:

```
<select name='id'>
```

Comment: Please read up on SQL injection vulnerabilities. Your script is vulnerable as it currently is to database tampering and hacking. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection In short, you should call mysql_real_escape_string() on ALL of the variables you use in your SQL query.

Comment: Example: `$quotetext = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['quotetext']);`

Comment: For integer values use: `intval($_POST['id']);`, for string values `mysql_real_escape_string()`. It's also wise to check if the magic quotes configuration value is set on the server with `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` and use `stripslashes()` on your GPC variables if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form, you are using `<select name='name'>`, but in your PHP script you're calling for `$_POST['id']`.
Change it to:

```
<select name='id'>
```

Comment: WHAMMO! Good eye, thank you sir. I will put this as accepted soon as I can.

Answer (score 4):

At first glance, it looks like a typo. Try:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't have a form variable with "id" as its name. It looks to me as you just need to change `<select name='name'>` to `<select name='id'>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$team_id = $_POST['name']
```

Your select element is named "name" and your form is "POST".

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

to

```
$id = $_POST['name']; // as name is what you gave your select element
```